# generate a skewed distribution within a range that should become normal after a power transformation

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

I'd like to generate a S=sequence of numbers within a range min..max (or mean/sd) that is not normal, so Shapiro-Wilk Test would fail it. If I take log(S), it should be a normal distribution.

How can I generate in R such a sequence? I tried S=geoR::rboxcox(1000, lambda=3, mean=35, sd=2) for instance and *sometimes* the p-value of shapiro.test(S) is just above 0.05, whilst p-value of shapiro.test(log(S)) is below 0.01.

Are there better approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about how to do something in R (or other software) are off topic here. If you reword your question to emphasize the statiistical aspects, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta distributions with equal shape parameters, both fairly large, are nearly normal, but have support $(0,1).$

So take exponentials of such a beta to get a distribution of random variables $Y,$ which will have known support $(1, e),$ and will not be normal.

However,
$Z = \log(Y),$ should be sufficiently near normal to pass a Shapiro-Wilk test.

```
set.seed(2020)
y = exp(rbeta(500, 10, 10))
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.104   1.534   1.641   1.656   1.770   2.217 
shapiro.test(y)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  y
W = 0.99053, p-value = 0.002681    # Y strongly rejected as normal

z = log(y)
summary(z)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.09912 0.42771 0.49526 0.49832 0.57122 0.79614 
shapiro.test(z)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z
W = 0.99735, p-value = 0.6083      # not distinguishable from normal

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(z), sd(z)), add=T, col="red")
 curve(dbeta(x, 10, 10), add=T, col="blue")
```

[image]

In the figure above, the red curve is the a normal density with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ matching $\bar Z$ and $S_Z,$ respectively.
The blue curve is the density of $\mathsf{Beta}(10,10).$

*Note:* [Linear functions of beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters) can have suitable support
$(A, B),$ with $A < B,$ other than $(0,1).$